# Zend Framework 2 Database Access in Models

Tags: php, database, model, zend-framework2

I am developing my app in `ZF2`  but despite trying i could not find answer for my database/model problem.

I think of TableGateway that is pretty much the copy of skeleton application example as a AdminUser collection of some sorts that does the query tasks and returns AdminUser instance.

this is part of Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{

    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Admin\Model\AdminUserTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('AdminUserTableGateway');
                $table = new AdminUserTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'AdminUserTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new AdminUser());
                return new TableGateway('zxf_admin_user', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

here is the controller

```
protected $adminUserTable;

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->layout('layout/admin');

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'text' => 'some text',
        'users' => $this->getAdminUserTable()->fetchAll(),
    ));
}

public function getAdminUserTable()
{
    if (!$this->adminUserTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->adminUserTable = $sm->get('Admin\Model\AdminUserTable');
    }
    return $this->adminUserTable;
}
```

I am not sure of the getAdminUserTable approach,and this is the function that gets user

```
public function getAdminUser($id)
{
    $id  = (int) $id;
    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
    $row = $rowset->current();
    if (!$row) {
        throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
    }
    return $row;
}
```

but what if I am interested in having another class something like AdminUserPriviliges that would be object that is returned when you do this in your controller

```
    $user = $this->getAdminUserTable()->getAdminUser($id);
```

to get privileges even though they are different class and data for them is stored in different table, hence the below method would need to perform database search but because inside AdminUser object it could use the $this->id and furthermore via AdminUser you would get access to privileges themselves so I could then get them on request as a collection of objects, something like this

```
    $user_piviliges = $user->getPriviliges();
```

and the content should be collection of AdminUserPriviliges instances

```
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'text' => 'some text',
        'user' => $this->getAdminUserTable()->getAdminUser($id);,
    ));
```

so sending user objects back to view would mean we have the privileges too.
in a similar way when i move to other entities i would like to be able to do the same

like $product->getImages() would give you all images but they are not stored in the same table of course.

Is there a better way to do it or even simpler?

Answer (score 2):

Your `getAdminUserTable` and similar functions are doing work that the service manager already does for you. By default, each call to `$sm->get('Admin\Model\AdminUserTable');` during one request will return the same object.
For example, say I have this service:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{    
    return array(
            'factories' => array(
                    'TestService' =>  function($sm) {
                        return time();
                    },
            ),
    );
}
```

and I use it in a controller action like this:

```
public function testAction()
{
    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $first = $sm->get('TestService');
    sleep(1);
    $second = $sm->get('TestService');

    echo $first;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $second;

    return $this->response;
}
```

If you execute that, you'll see that the two numbers printed are always the same. This is because both $first and $second are referring to the same object, that was created when you first called `$sm->get('TestService');`.

If you don't want that behavior, you need to specify that in the `shared` key of your config.

```
    'shared' => array(
            // Indicate services that should **NOT** be
            // shared -- i.e., ones where you want a different instance
            // every time.
            'TestService' => false,
    )
```

If I understand the rest of your question, it boils down to building your own domain objects and using those in the controller instead of directly using your table gateways in the controller. If so, yes, that's a very good idea for any site that does more than just representing your database data in a straightforward way (straightforward as in: one Film table translates to one film list page and one film detail page, with minimal extra logic).

Just be careful that you don't end up loading way more data than you need to. For example, a User will probably not be a very heavy object, and it might make sense to load all data of at least the current user into an object. But say you have a Product table that is linked to most of the other tables in your database (product info, shipping info, components...). You probably want to avoid putting all that info in an object if all you're really doing is presenting a list of product names.

**Edited in response to comment**

What are your issues then exactly? How to implement a method like getProfiles in a User class? You'd do something like

```
public function getPrivileges() {
    $privTable = new TableGateway('PRIVILEGES', $adapter);
    $rowset = $privTable->select(array('USER' => $this->id));
    $privileges = array();

    foreach ($rowset as $row) {
        $priv = new Privilege;
        $priv.setType($row['TYPE']);
        //...set other properties
        $privileges[] = $priv;
    }

    return $privileges;
}
```

Or if you need to get info from multiple tables, you don't use a TableGateway but construct your own Zend Sql/Select object, where you're free to add any joins, wheres etc. See http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.db.sql.html.

Comment: interensting suggestions Gert, i also have considered it might be overload and that it might be better to call other objects related to current one outside of the object itself, but you must agree with me it is not necessary answer for my issues, thanks for trying, Tom

Comment: I edited my response. The main message is that you're free to use any number of table gateways or other queries in your own classes. Maybe what confused you was that the original example constructs the gateway and table objects as entries in the service manager, but basically there's nothing special about service manager objects, they're just normal objects that are created when you access them.

Comment: yes I know that I can use/create TableGateway within my Model/Class but but where did you get $adapter from that is why my question states ZF2 Database Access in Models, sorry if I got you confused with all that stuff about accessing models from models I just wanted to justify my reasons, sorry if I have missinterpreted your answer should i be missing something

Comment: That $adapter object could be inserted into the User object via the constructor, like new User($sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')).

Comment: ok then, not nicest i am used to do something more like this __construct($id = null) { ... } to be passed to constructor, and I cannot confirm that it works, can you expand on your answer by providing constructor code (working one would be the best), then when I put it to test, I promise this weekend, I will accept the answer, thanks

Comment: sorry had no time, but i will remember you in future that you are still waiting for some points for this one